# Can I programmatically control the sound volume on a application level?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio

*SoundBunny* does exactly what I need, the ability to mute/unmute and change the volume of the audio, on demand, at an individual application level. Unfortunately I can't control it via *AppleScript* as it's not scriptable.

What other options do I have?

I found a way to mute a particular audio queue based on a reference to it by using :

```
AudioQueueSetParameter(audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 0);
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to retrieve all audio queues currently in use by other applications(don't know if that's possible). I only found documentation how to create and manipulate one.

Comment: I don't know if this is generally possible for applications which are not yours. Further on, I don't know if it's a valid presumption that all applications even use the _AudioQueue_ API. Many of them don't.

Comment: Is there any other way I can control the audio of other applications? There must be, since SoundBunny is already doing it.

Comment: If there is a commercial application intercepting output volume level controls of running programs and modifying them, then it must be possible. Perhaps you'll have to write your own program. Perhaps you could also ask for API info on Apple developer forums.

Comment: System wide OS X audio volume changes likely require installing a custom kernel/kext or other OS modification.